# CTF input file for CNTK. Entire sequence (dynamic axis) in one single line without Sequence ID

Tags: cntk

I have a model with multiple fixed size inputs and one dynamic axis input. I was creating a CTF format file for this. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/cntk/wiki/BrainScript-CNTKTextFormat-Reader), for dynamic size input we should keep the CTF input as

```
0 |word 234:1 |tag 12:1
0 |word 123:1 |tag 10:1
0 |word 123:1 |tag 13:1
1 |word 234:1 |tag 12:1
1 |word 123:1 |tag 10:1
...
```

I was wondering if we can change this to a single line input without needing to specify explicit sequence IDs, something like this

```
|word 234:1 |tag 12:1 |word 123:1 |tag 10:1 |word 123:1 |tag 13:1
|word 234:1 |tag 12:1 |word 123:1 |tag 10:1
```

Can this be done? Will the CTFDeserializer maintain the order of the sequence in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is allowed. If sequence IDs are omitted, every line will be interpreted as a new sequence.

Comment: But will this maintain the sequence order properly? I mean will all the one-hot "word" vectors and one-hot "tag" vectors be in the correct order?

Comment: No, you cannot rely on word order being maintained without sequence IDs.